# The average time before the first appearance of a sequence of a length 3 of Bernoulli r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, expected-value, martingales

Let $\{X_n,n \geq 1\}$  be i.i.d. random variables of Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p \in (0,1)$.

Let $\tau_{ijk}:=\inf\{n\geq 3: (X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n) = (i,j,k)\}$ with $i,j,k \in \{0,1\}$.

How can I calculate $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}], \mathbb{E}[\tau_{100}]$ or any other?

If I wanted to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|(X_2, X_1, X_0) = (1,1,1)] $, I would apply the following theorem for the Markov chain $\{Z_n\}_{n\geq 2}:=(X_{n-2}, X_{n-1}, X_n)$ on finite state space (8 states $(0,0,0);(0,0,1)...$):

"An irreducible Markov chain ${Z_n}$ has at most one invariant distribution $\pi(z)$. It certainly has one if it is finite. And $\forall$ $ z $ $\pi(z)=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[T_z|Z_0=z]},$ where $T_z:=\inf\{n\geq 1: Z_n=z\} $."

The invariant distribution here is $\pi(z)=\frac{1}{8} \forall z$, so $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|(X_2, X_1, X_0) = (1,1,1)] = \mathbb{E}[\tau_{ijk}|(X_2, X_1, X_0) = (i,j,k)] = 8 $.
Though it doesn't give any clues on how to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}]$.

Comment: Don't you just get the result $\mathbb{E}\tau=8$? The given thing is nothing but the initial condition.

Comment: I've got the result of the average time of return to the same state where we started, but not the average time of the first appearance without any conditions, which is more complicated and involves Martingale theory as far as I know.

Comment: If you start with different state I think you can find similar questions on Grimmett's Probability and Random Processes. I remember doing similar problems there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $\mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}] = E$. Then,
$$
E = \mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 0]\cdot \frac12 + \mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1]\cdot \frac12 = (E+1)\cdot \frac12 + \mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1]\cdot \frac12.
$$
Further,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1] = \mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1,X_1=0]\cdot \frac12 + \mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1,X_1 = 1]\cdot \frac12\\ = (E+2)\cdot \frac12 + \mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1,X_1 = 1]\cdot \frac12.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1,X_1 = 1] = (E+3)\cdot \frac12 + \mathbb{E}[\tau_{111}|X_0 = 1,X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1]\cdot\frac12
= \frac{E}2 + 3. 
$$
Combining these equalities,
$$
E = \frac{E}2 + \frac12 + \frac{E}4 + \frac12 +\frac{E}8 + \frac34,
$$
whence $E = 14$ ($\tau_{111}$ is obviously bounded by $3$ times a geometric random variable, so $E<\infty$).

---

Actually, we could arrive at the same result sooner if took for granted that $\mathbb E[T_z| Z_0=z] = 8$. Indeed, conditioning, as above, on the first step, we get
$$
E[T_z| Z_0=z] = 1\cdot \frac 12 + (E+1)\cdot \frac12 = 8,
$$
whence $E=14$.